# Arduino, turn on the led when input is HIGH and turn off when input is LOW

Tags: arduino

i want to turn on the LED from Arduino when the input from PIN 2 is HIGH.
The problem is that the LED stays ON for a few seconds even afther the value from input PIN 2 is low.

Can someone help me please?

Below is my code from loop(). I declared in setup() the pins mode corectly.

```
if(digitalRead(2)==HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
} else {
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Friend if not use external ide (for programming) check examples please ! Examples > digital >button

Comment: Is that all your code in `loop()`?

Comment: Yes, it is all the code :)   I found that is something wrong with the board. Thank you anyway!